# Proper permissions on web directory

Tags: permissions

I have a problem with trying to give the permissions on the web directory.

I've changed the group owner of `/var/www` to `www-data` and I've added the user `amitger1` (ftp user who uploads the files to the web directory) to the `www-data group`, then I've set the permissions to 770 but when I upload a new file it appears with 600 permissions.

How can I do to change the permissions of all the new files to 770?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set g+s on the directory in order to new files to inherit the permissions from the directory.

Comment: So i just need to add +s to chmod?

Comment: Should do the trick, I think. You might want to make it recursive though.

Comment: seems that +s is not a valid option for chmod

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say g+s. The option means something very different for users rather than groups. You want it for groups.

Comment: i dont know why but it doesn't work